# Powerpoint layout algorithm for box-in-box view

Tags: vba, layout, powerpoint

I am trying to write some code in VBA and PowerPoint to automatically create a poster (basically a box in box view)  however, its proving to be a little more challenging than my skills can cope.

looking to get some guidance on how best to structure the code (and patterns)
at the moment:

- Im reading the data (see table) from csv, and placing them into 4 in memory arrays (cat, sub-cat, column, intersection) - this is probably bad - but dont know of anything better.
- my code tries to process the spacing logic and adjusts the x-and-y pos of each intersection block (grows the category and sub-category blocks when needed) within the arrays, then finally draws/places the blocks on the powerpoint canvas.
- You will see in the graphic "initial selected block" at the moment thats the context from which i run -- the idea is to use that block size as the template for the dimensions

Im not worried about the placement, its more the algorithm to determine the spacing (or block size of each of the components

below is a sample of the data that I read:
[image]

and once the logic is generated, this is how the "poster" would look
[image]

Im happy to share code, its just getting a bit big now (and I feel im missing a trick in terms of simplicity)

code sample included below:

```
Const defaultObjectWidth = 95
Const defaultObjectHeight = 50
Const defaultCategoryWidth = 90
Const defaultSubCatWidth = 90
Const defaultBuffer = 3
Const blocksPerCol = 4
Const myYAxisWidth = 100

Sub insertShape()
On Error GoTo Err_Handler
  Dim SlideHeight As Long, SlideWidth As Long
  Dim ContainerHeight As Long, ContainerWidth As Long
  Dim ObjectHeight As Long, ObjectWidth As Long
  Dim x As Long, y As Long
  Dim shp As Object
  Dim colWidth As Integer
  Dim blockSize As Integer
  Dim IntersectCalcComplete As Boolean
  
  IntersectCalcComplete = False
  
  ' create the Arrays for storing the data
  Dim CategorysArr()  As String
  Dim SubCatsArr()  As String
  Dim YAxissArr() As String
  Dim IntersectsArr() As String
  Dim tmpIntersects() As String

  
Call LoadSubCats(SubCatsArr)
Call LoadCategorys(CategorysArr)
Call LoadYAxiss(YAxissArr)
Call LoadIntersects(IntersectsArr)
    
  
ReDim tmpIntersects(0 To 2, 0 To 0)
  
  If ActiveWindow.Selection.Type = ppSelectionNone Then
    MsgBox "Please select object", vbExclamation, "Make Selection"
  Else
    Set shp = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1)
    
    SlideHeight = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideHeight 'get slide vertical height
    SlideWidth = ActivePresentation.PageSetup.SlideWidth  'get slide horizontal width
    'Main Content Container width and height
    ContainerHeight = shp.Height
    ContainerWidth = shp.Width
    
    
    ' calculate the container column sizes.
    '
    colWidth = calcColumnSizes(shp.Width, CategorysArr, SubCatsArr, YAxissArr)
    ' calculate the blockwidth based on the density factor parameter
    blockWidth = calcBlockWidth(colWidth, blocksPerCol)
    
    ' Iterate through the Categorys, SubCats and Intersects in order to calculate the spacing of the Intersects.
    
             ' first sort the matricies by a specific column.
             ' CategorysArr = QuickSortArray(CategorysArr, -1, -1, 4)
             ' Call multiSortArray(1, CategorysArr, arrFlds(CategorysArr), "2 Asc 5 Asc")
   ' -- ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    Dim SubCatID As Integer
    'Dim myYAxisWidth As Integer
    Dim SubCatHeight, CategoryHeight, currentX, currentY, n, t As Integer
    
    SubCatHeight = 0
    CategoryHeight = 0
    currentX = 0
    currentY = 0
    currentBlockUsed = 0
    
    For i = LBound(SubCatsArr, 2) To UBound(SubCatsArr, 2) ' For each SubCat in the SubCats Array
    
    t = t + 1
    'Debug.Print (" processing SubCat: " & t & " called: " & SubCatsArr(1, i))
    
       ' Debug.Print (SubCatsArr(i, 1)) ' print the name
        SubCatID = SubCatsArr(0, i)
        If Not IsNull(SubCatID) Then
            ' with each SubCat - find all related Intersects and fit them into the canvas
            
            ' 1: Filter the Intersects by SubCat
            Call getIntersectBySubCat(SubCatID, IntersectsArr, tmpIntersects)
            'printArray (tmpIntersects)
            ' 2: re-structure the Intersects position to fit into the YAxiss allocated
          '  myYAxisWidth = 200  ' -- get YAxis width TODO: get the real width
                               ' -- we already know what the blockWidth is (above)
             SubCatHeight = defaultObjectHeight + defaultBuffer  ' set the SubCatheight on the first pass.
            For j = LBound(tmpIntersects, 2) To UBound(tmpIntersects, 2)  ' Loop through tmp Intersects to add placement
           
            
            If LBound(tmpIntersects, 2) = -1 Then   ' SubCat has no Intersects
            ' Debug.Print ("SubCat ID:" & SubCatID & " has no Intersects")
            
            
            Else
                If myYAxisWidth < (currentX + blockWidth + (defaultBuffer * 2)) Then  ' If there is not enough remaining space in YAxis
                    currentY = currentY + defaultBuffer + defaultObjectHeight
                    currentX = 0
                    SubCatHeight = SubCatHeight + defaultObjectHeight + defaultBuffer
                End If
                n = findArrStr(IntersectsArr, 0, str(tmpIntersects(0, j)))
                IntersectsArr(6, n) = str(currentX + defaultBuffer)  ' X CoOrdinate
                IntersectsArr(7, n) = str(currentY + defaultBuffer)  ' Y CoOrdinate
            
                currentX = currentX + defaultBuffer + defaultObjectWidth
            
            End If
            
            
            Next j 'filtered Intersect
        Else
      '  Debug.Print ("empty record in Array Detected")
        End If
        
         Call setSubCatHeight(SubCatHeight, SubCatID, SubCatsArr, CategorysArr)
        SubCatHeight = 0
        
        
    Next i 'SubCat
    
    
    
    
' -- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
' -- -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ' ADDING OF THE SHAPES TO THE VIEW
   
   Call addCategorys(CategorysArr, shp)
   Call addSubCats(SubCatsArr, shp)
   Call addIntersects(IntersectsArr, shp)
    
    
   ' x = (SlideWidth - ObjectWidth) / 2 'calculate horizontal position
   ' y = (SlideHeight - ObjectHeight) / 2 'calculate vertical position
   ' shp.Left = x 'move object horizontal
   ' shp.Top = y 'move object vertical
  End If
  
Exit_Label:
  On Error Resume Next
  Set shp = Nothing
  Exit Sub
Err_Handler:
  MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Exit_Label

End Sub
Function getIntersectBySubCat(SubCatID As Integer, ByRef IntersectsArr As Variant, ByRef tmpIntersects As Variant)
' Filters the Intersects to the specific SubCat
 Dim i, j As Integer
 j = -1

 Erase tmpIntersects
 ReDim Preserve tmpIntersects(0 To 2, -1 To 0)
 
 For i = LBound(IntersectsArr, 2) To UBound(IntersectsArr, 2)
    If IntersectsArr(2, i) = SubCatID Then  'if the Intersect relates to the current SubCat
        j = j + 1
        ReDim Preserve tmpIntersects(0 To 2, 0 To j)  ' Redimension:
 
        tmpIntersects(0, j) = IntersectsArr(0, i)  ' Intersect Code
        tmpIntersects(1, j) = IntersectsArr(3, i) ' get the YAxis
        tmpIntersects(2, j) = IntersectsArr(9, i) ' get the Order
        
        
        
        'Debug.Print ("RESULT ARRAY" & tmpIntersects(i + 1, 0) & "_" & tmpIntersects(i + 1, 1) & "_" & tmpIntersects(i + 1, 2) & "_")
    End If
 
 Next i 'Intersect
    
    ' sort the array by the Intersect order column (2)
   ' Call QuickSortArray(tmpIntersects, , , 2)



End Function

Function calcColumnSizes(lenContainer As Integer, ByRef CategorysArr As Variant, ByRef SubCatsArr As Variant, ByRef YAxissArr As Variant) As Integer
Dim lenCategory, lenSubCat, cntQtr As Integer
Dim lenWorkArea, columnSize As Integer


cntQtr = UBound(YAxissArr) + 1

lenWorkArea = lenContainer - defaultCategoryWidth - defaultSubCatWidth - (2 * defaultBuffer)
lenWorkArea = lenWorkArea - ((2 * defaultBuffer) + (cntQtr * defaultBuffer))
columnSize = lenWorkArea / cntQtr

' now propogate the columnSize into the YAxiss data
    For i = LBound(YAxissArr, 1) To UBound(YAxissArr, 1)
        YAxissArr(2, i) = str(Round(columnSize, 1)) ' Width
    Next i
 calcColumnSizes = columnSize

End Function

Function calcBlockWidth(columnSize As Integer, density As Integer) As Integer
    calcBlockWidth = columnSize / density

End Function

Function setSubCatHeight(SubCatYPos, ID As Integer, ByRef SubCatsArr As Variant, ByRef CategorysArr As Variant)
Dim curSubCat As Integer
    curSubCat = findArrStr(SubCatsArr, 0, str(ID))
    If SubCatsArr(3, curSubCat) < SubCatYPos Then
        SubCatsArr(3, curSubCat) = SubCatYPos
       Call setCategoryHeight(SubCatYPos, CInt(SubCatsArr(2, curSubCat)), CategorysArr)
    End If


End Function
Function setCategoryHeight(CategoryYPos, ID As Integer, ByRef CategorysArr As Variant)
Dim curCategory As Integer
    curCategory = findArrStr(CategorysArr, 0, str(ID))
    If CategorysArr(2, curCategory) < CategoryYPos Then
        CategorysArr(2, curCategory) = CategoryYPos
    End If
End Function
Function addCategorys(ByRef CategorysArr As Variant, masterShp As Shape)

Dim i, j As Integer

For i = LBound(CategorysArr, 2) To UBound(CategorysArr, 2)
    Call addBlockContents(CInt(CategorysArr(2, i)), CInt(CategorysArr(3, i)), CStr(CategorysArr(1, i)), masterShp)  ' X, Y, Name, Shape
Next i
    
End Function
Function addSubCats(ByRef SubCatsArr As Variant, masterShp As Shape)

Dim i, j As Integer

For i = LBound(SubCatsArr, 2) To UBound(SubCatsArr, 2)
    Call addBlockContents(CInt(SubCatsArr(3, i)), CInt(SubCatsArr(4, i)), CStr(SubCatsArr(1, i)), masterShp)
Next i
    
End Function


Function addIntersects(ByRef IntersectsArr As Variant, masterShp As Shape)

Dim i, j As Integer
Dim myX, myY As Integer
myX = 0
myY = 0
For i = LBound(IntersectsArr, 2) To UBound(IntersectsArr, 2)

' adjust the placement of the shape relative to the masterShape
myX = masterShp.Left + CInt(IntersectsArr(6, i)) + defaultCategoryWidth + defaultSubCatWidth + (defaultBuffer * 2)
myY = masterShp.Top + CInt(IntersectsArr(7, i))
Call addBlockContents(myX, myY, CStr(IntersectsArr(1, i)), masterShp)



         'For j = LBound(COAArray, 2) To UBound(COAArray, 2)
         'Next j
     Next i
    
End Function


Function addBlockContents(x, y, IntersectName As String, myShp As Shape)
Dim oSh As Shape

Set oSh = ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange.Shapes.AddShape(msoShapeRectangle, x, y, defaultObjectWidth, defaultObjectHeight)
    With oSh
     With .Fill
        .Visible = msoTrue
        .ForeColor.ObjectThemeColor = msoThemeColorText2
        .ForeColor.TintAndShade = 0
        .ForeColor.Brightness = 0.8000000119
        .Transparency = 0
        .Solid
    End With 'fill
      With .TextFrame
        .MarginLeft = 0
        .MarginRight = 0
        .MarginTop = 0
        .MarginBottom = 0
        .AutoSize = False
        
       With .TextRange
          .Text = IntersectName
           With .Font
            .Name = "Ariel"
            .Size = 6.4
            .Bold = msoFalse
            .Italic = msoFalse
            .Underline = msoFalse
            .Shadow = msoFalse
            .Emboss = msoFalse
            .BaselineOffset = 0
            .AutoRotateNumbers = msoFalse
            .Color.SchemeColor = ppForeground
        End With   ' Font
       End With   ' TextRange
       End With   ' TextFrame
End With   ' oSh, the shape itself
'Set addBlockContents = oSh
End Function
```

any help will be awesome!

Comment: Do you really use "arrays"? Aren't they ranges? Please, edit your question and post the code you use. We will maybe better understand what you try accomplishing...

Comment: @FaneDuru If you're thinking of "ranges" in the Excel sense of the word, remember that Hightower's writing this in PowerPoint, which doesn't have the kind of ranges that Excel does.

Comment: Ok..  you can see its hacky -- yes I use arrays, ( by using Excel Ranges) would that mean that i should integrate to Excel? - i do like the ide to use tables...  -Also.. I want this to be a pretty poster - so PowerPoint Layout is most desired.

Comment: Using a 2-dimensional array, you can keep all the data in one array. You're basically creating a table of values. Here's an article with more information about how to set them up and use them: https://www.homeandlearn.org/multidimensional_arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to get started here is to use tables. It will help you with a lot of the layout issues.
As a first step, create a table manually. Insert a table and remove headings and other automatic coloring. Set the border line to maximum width and to match the background color before applying it to all cells.
Now you can merge cells to create larger boxes (like *Cars* in your example). Deleting cells isn't possible, but you can set the background color.
If this is good enough, then you have something to automate.
If not, then you can perhaps use this to find coordinates for boxes to create.